# Restart an errored workflow programmatically

Tags: 2010, workflow, visual-studio, error-handling

I am trying to figure out the best way to restart an errored out workflow.

A little background: 
We get seemingly random error-outs (error and stack below) in a visual studio created workflow when an item updates itself. This is very difficult to replicate, and my initial thoughts are that the workflow gets to the `System.Update()` step before the item is added to the database.

The fix is always very simple: cancel the workflow, and re-run it manually. I thought to just add these two steps to the error handler of the workflow, but I am wary of getting into an infinite loop of errors.

I thought about adding a counter to a hidden column, but in the off chance that the item is still not created in the database, then I would get an error from inside the error handler (SPD workflow inception XD).

We don't want to add a delay to the start of the workflow either as the `System.Update()` updates the color of the item and will probably cause more issues than the random error-outs.

Is there a better way to do this or an easier way to do this?

**Error:** Item does not exist. The page you selected contains an item that does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.

**Stack Trace:**

```
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx) 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddOrUpdateItem(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystemUpdate, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bUpdateNoVersion, Int32& plID, String& pbstrGuid, Guid pbstrNewDocId, Boolean bHasNewDocId, String bstrVersion, Object& pvarAttachmentNames, Object& pvarAttachmentContents, Object& pvarProperties, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, String bstrFileName, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pListDataValidationCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pRestrictInsertCallback, ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pUniqueFieldCallback) 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.AddOrUpdateItem(Boolean bAdd, Boolean bSystem, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Guid newGuidOnAdd, Int32& ulID, Object& objAttachmentNames, Object& objAttachmentContents, Boolean suppressAfterEvents, String filename) 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.UpdateInternal(Boolean bSystem, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Guid newGuidOnAdd, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean suppressAfterEvents, String filename) 
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.SystemUpdate() 
at Attendance_Calendar.AttendanceCalendarWorkflow.onWorkflowActivated1_Invoked(Object sender, ExternalDataEventArgs e) 
at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.Activity.RaiseGenericEvent[T](DependencyProperty dependencyEvent, Object sender, T e) 
at System.Workflow.Activities.HandleExternalEventActivity.RaiseEvent(Object[] args) 
at System.Workflow.Activities.HandleExternalEventActivity.Execute(ActivityExecutionContext executionContext) 
at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.ActivityExecutor1.Execute(T activity, ActivityExecutionContext executionContext) 
at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.ActivityExecutor1.Execute(Activity activity, ActivityExecutionContext executionContext) 
at System.Workflow.ComponentModel.ActivityExecutorOperation.Run(IWorkflowCoreRuntime workflowCoreRuntime) 
at System.Workflow.Runtime.Scheduler.Run()
```